# Creating line-strings from points in MySQL

Tags: mysql, linestring, mysql-spatial

I am extracting the lat/long information from Geo-tagged images and storing them in MySQL. I want to get a line-string from the points, I looked into the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function but I am not able to get it to work with the linestring. Is there a way to store the concatenated geometries of the individual points as a linestring?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to get it to work properly"? Please edit your question with more information, such as an error message.

Comment: I want to store the concatenated geometries as a linestring, I got the `GROUP_CONCAT()` to work but that doesn't really help me.

Comment: Have you considered using PostgreSQL which has better support for geometry types? If MySQL is a requirement, could you post sample rows and code?

Comment: I shifted over to PostgresSQL and it was fairly simple there, just had to use  `ST_MakeLine(geom)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shifted over to PostgresSQL and it was fairly simple there, just had to use `ST_MakeLine(geom)`